# A graph with two values as points and mean value with other shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

### Problem:

I can't find the right way to make a plot with values from a given variable with points and plot the value of the mean with another different shape. So far I find a way of doing this, but mean value appears in the color legend also which is something I don't want to. How could I get the desired output? Should I use `stat_summary`?

NOTE: Variables must be ordered by the mean value among groups by multimorbidity (if it is something important for the solution proposed) this is why I am using `reorder_within` and `scale_x_reordered`.

```r
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dgrtwo/drlib/master/R/reorder_within.R")
library(tidyverse)

foo %>% 
  group_by(multimorbidity, variables) %>% 
  mutate(Mean = mean(varimportance),
         aux_mean = Mean) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(Gender, varimportance) %>% 
  gather(Gender, varimportance, -multimorbidity, -variables, -aux_mean) %>%
  mutate(type = if_else(Gender %in% c("Male", "Female"), "Gender", "Mean")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder_within(variables, aux_mean, multimorbidity), varimportance, 
                color = Gender, shape = type)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(multimorbidity~., scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

### The desired output:

[image]

### `dput` for `foo`:

```r
foo <- structure(list(
      Gender = c(
        "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male",
        "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female",
        "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male",
        "Male"
      ), multimorbidity = c(
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes",
        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes",
        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"
      ), variables = c(
        "bmi", "income",
        "soccap", "alternattr", "occhaz", "bmi", "income", "soccap",
        "alternattr", "occhaz", "bmi", "income", "soccap", "alternattr",
        "occhaz", "bmi", "income", "soccap", "alternattr", "occhaz"
      ),
      varimportance = c(
        73.1234145437324, 51.0029811829917, 100,
        0, 90.9926659603591, 81.1949541852942, 48.2402164701156,
        100, 0, 9.10509052698692, 66.7759248406279, 31.69991730502,
        100, 4.7914221037359, 93.4636133674693, 70.8853809607131,
        75.004433319282, 100, 0, 43.7326141975936
      )
    ), class = c(
      "tbl_df",
      "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: Does imposing limits on your colour scale work for you? I.e. add something like `scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("Female", "Male"))` to the ggplot code.